# Does WSO2 CEP support the Solace Messaging System Integration?

Tags: wso2, solace-mq, solace, wso2-cep

I am trying to implement the Solace messaging system integration with WS02 CEP.

Is there any direct connectivity integration existing? Or can I use the separate layer(Active MQ) to integrate these two?
If possible any document can you please share with us.

Answer (score 1):

WSO2 CEP consists of event adapters for various protocols (HTTP, JMS, Thrift, MQTT and etc). If Solace supports JMS you can integrate with CEP using JMS event adapters where you can have a broker like ActiveMQ.

There are [samples](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP310/Samples) where JMS has been used and also please refer the [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP310/Working+with+Event+Adapters) as well.